# Installing gcc-4.8 on Ubuntu 21.10 in 2022

Tags: compiling, gcc

I am trying to install GCC-4.8 on Ubuntu 21.10.

First, I tried installing from a repository, but failed probably because version 4.8 is too old:

```
>sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
>sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
>sudo apt-get update
>sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8
```

The output of the last command was:

```
>sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.8-hppa64' for regex 'gcc-4.8'
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfwupdplugin1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Second, I tried to compile from sources. I ran these commands:

```
>wget http://www.netgull.com/gcc/releases/gcc-4.8.0/gcc-4.8.0.tar.bz2
>tar xjf gcc-4.8.0.tar.bz2 
>sudo apt-get install libgm
>cd gcc-4.8.0/
>./contrib/download_prerequisites 
>./configure --prefix=/app/gcc/4.8.0
>make -j 8
```

But eventually I got this error:

```
In file included from ./tm.h:42,
                 from ../.././gcc/cp/init.c:26:
../.././gcc/defaults.h:126:24: warning: invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and string macro [-Wliteral-suffix]
  126 |       fprintf ((FILE), ","HOST_WIDE_INT_PRINT_UNSIGNED",%u\n",  \
      |                        ^
../.././gcc/cp/except.c: In function ‘int doing_eh()’:
../.././gcc/cp/except.c:468:11: warning: unquoted option name ‘-fexceptions’ in format [-Wformat-diag]
  468 |    error ("exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable");
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../.././gcc/cp/except.c:1005:
cfns.gperf: At global scope:
cfns.gperf:101:1: error: ‘const char* libc_name_p(const char*, unsigned int)’ redeclared inline with ‘gnu_inline’ attribute
cfns.gperf:26:14: note: ‘const char* libc_name_p(const char*, unsigned int)’ previously declared here
cfns.gperf:26:14: warning: inline function ‘const char* libc_name_p(const char*, unsigned int)’ used but never defined
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1058: cp/except.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
../.././gcc/cp/friend.c: In function ‘tree_node* do_friend(tree, tree, tree, tree, overload_flags, bool)’:
../.././gcc/cp/friend.c:590:15: warning: unquoted sequence of 2 consecutive punctuation characters ‘<>’ in format [-Wformat-diag]
  590 |      "and add <> after the function name here) ");
      |               ^~
../.././gcc/cp/friend.c:590:47: warning: spurious trailing space in format [-Wformat-diag]
  590 |      "and add <> after the function name here) ");
      |                                               ^
../.././gcc/cp/init.c: In function ‘tree_node* build_java_class_ref(tree)’:
../.././gcc/cp/init.c:3028:10: warning: contraction ‘can%'t’ in format; use ‘cannot’ instead [-Wformat-diag]
 3028 |  error ("can%'t find %<class$%> in %qT", type);
      |          ^~~~~~
rm gcc.pod
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/sda/Program_files/gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:4163: all-stage1-gcc] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sda/Program_files/gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:23575: stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sda/Program_files/gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0'
make: *** [Makefile:892: all] Error 2
```

My gcc is "gcc version 10.3.0 (Ubuntu 10.3.0-11ubuntu1)". I am guessing that new GCC compiler can not build such an old one.

Please advise.

=============================================

FOLLOW-UP

I tried to follow an advice given below, and re-compiled in a different folder - same output, an error, but a different one.

I used the following commands:

```
tar xjf gcc-4.8.0.tar.bz2 
./gcc-4.8.0/contrib/download_prerequisites 
mkdir build
cd build/
../gcc-4.8.0/configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-4.8.0
make -j 16
```

The output was:

```
../../gcc-4.8.0/gcc/cp/semantics.c: In function ‘tree_node* finish_omp_clauses(tree)’:
../../gcc-4.8.0/gcc/cp/semantics.c:4150:16: warning: unquoted identifier or keyword ‘num_threads’ in format [-Wformat-diag]
 4150 |        error ("num_threads expression must be integral");
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~
../../gcc-4.8.0/gcc/cp/semantics.c: In function ‘tree_node* finish_trait_expr(cp_trait_kind, tree, tree)’:
../../gcc-4.8.0/gcc/cp/semantics.c:5614:15: warning: unquoted identifier or keyword ‘__is_convertible_to’ in format [-Wformat-diag]
 5614 |       sorry ("__is_convertible_to");
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../gcc-4.8.0/gcc/cp/semantics.c: In function ‘tree_node* cxx_eval_call_expression(const constexpr_call*, tree, bool, bool, bool*, bool*)’:
../../gcc-4.8.0/gcc/cp/semantics.c:6797:10: warning: unquoted option name ‘-fconstexpr-depth’ in format [-Wformat-diag]
 6797 |         "-fconstexpr-depth= to increase the maximum)",
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../gcc-4.8.0/gcc/cp/semantics.c: In function ‘tree_node* finish_decltype_type(tree, bool, tsubst_flags_t)’:
../../gcc-4.8.0/gcc/cp/semantics.c:5326:11: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
 5326 |           if (DECL_BIT_FIELD_TYPE (expr))
      |           ^~
../../gcc-4.8.0/gcc/cp/semantics.c:5333:9: note: here
 5333 |         case FUNCTION_DECL:
      |         ^~~~
../../gcc-4.8.0/gcc/cp/semantics.c: In function ‘bool potential_constant_expression_1(tree, bool, tsubst_flags_t)’:
../../gcc-4.8.0/gcc/cp/semantics.c:8640:7: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
 8640 |       if (!literal_type_p (TREE_TYPE (t)))
      |       ^~
../../gcc-4.8.0/gcc/cp/semantics.c:8650:5: note: here
 8650 |     case INIT_EXPR:
      |     ^~~~
rm gcc.pod
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/sda/Program_files/gcc-build/build/gcc'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:4157: all-stage1-gcc] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sda/Program_files/gcc-build/build'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:21520: stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sda/Program_files/gcc-build/build'
make: *** [Makefile:886: all] Error 2
```

Any other suggestions?

My personal gut feeling is that the problem is in GCC v. 10.3.1 that is being used to compile GCC v. 4.8.0. The new GCC might not be compatible with the older source code.

Please advice

Comment: Two things: 1. GCC has [always recommended](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) that you don't try build `gcc` directly in the source directory, the steps should actually be something like `cd ...; /contrib/download_prerequisites; mkdir build; cd build; ../configure ...; make ...`. 2. The `gcc-4.8` package probably installed a `gcc-4.8` command. You should use the `CC` environment variable to tell `make` and `configure` to use it (`export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.8; ../configure ...; make ...`)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it did not work - see update above. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What about the second note? It seems you have the `gcc-4.8` package, have you checked if running `gcc-4.8` works?